# material ui avatar display local image broken

Tags: material-ui

```
<Avatar style={{
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        float: 'left',
        objectFit:'cover',
        backgroundColor:'#aa0000',
      }} src='./image/head.png'/>
```

The Avatar display a broken image,I don't know why?Any body any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
imprt AvatarBg from './image/head.png'

<Avatar src={AvatarBg}/>
```

**After use the top code it works**